# Lighthouse false flag

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt, lighthouse

I put my website through the Lighthouse test via `web.dev` and there I am shown 2 "errors" that I can not quite comprehend.


1st point: "Form elements do not have associated labels".

Lighthouse thinks that I do not use a label for a form. However, I have the following in my code:

```
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" />
<label for="burger">
```

This is the only time I use `input` at all.

So why does this message come up then?


2nd point: "robots.txt is not valid".

I use the following content for my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /testlab/
Disallow: /en/page-not-found.htm
Disallow: /en/page-not-found.htm

User-agent: WebReaper
User-agent: WebCopier
User-agent: Offline Explorer
User-agent: HTTrack
User-agent: Microsoft.URL.Control
User-agent: EmailCollector
User-agent: penthesilea
Disallow: /

sitemap: https://link-to-sitemap.com
```

As far as I know, the content should be recognized by different crawlers.

So why do I see this as an error in the Lighthouse test?

Here is the link to the website, if you want to run the test on your own: https://type-error.netlify.app

A small note: I have set redirects and headers via a netlify.toml file, maybe this will help.

Edit: When running the Lighthouse Test with the Chrome Dev Tool, more information to the robots.txt show up: "Lighthouse was unable to download a robots.txt file".

Comment: do you want to share a link to the page, from what you have showed everything seems fine but there could be loads of reasons the errors are showing.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Yes, of course. Thats the link the webpage: https://type-error.netlify.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** **Form elements do not have associated labels**

You have an opening label element without any closing element or name.

```
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" />
<label for="burger">
```

You should have a closing tag and a proper label name.

```
<input id="burger" type="checkbox" />
<label for="burger">burger</label>
```

**2.** **robots.txt is not valid**

The "robots.txt is not valid" is indeed a false flag.
See - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/12936

I have run into the same issue on my own sites. However, when using the lighthouse for chrome extension it passes. There seems to be an issue with the dev tools version.

[image: lighthouse for chrome SEO audit]